# Achieve same boot speed as when battery is depleted

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, sleep, reboot

Most laptops “switch off” when the battery goes down below 7% and then once you plug back power to it and turn it on it loads extremely fast in a few seconds as compared to normal boots.

I was wondering if the same could be achieved using some utility/batch script/setting to make Windows to go to that state during shutdowns. So when I come back to start my laptop its quick sailing. I would like to do this on Windows 10 (1709).

I don't really care about shutdown time(s), who really does?
I just want fast startups.

Is this even possible, what is that “switchoff” state even called?

Comment: Likely it is set to go into low power ‘sleep’ mode when the battery is at 7% so it’s not actually powering off.  If you close the lid it normally does the same thing by default.

Comment: use hibernation all time to get fast boot speed

Comment: @magicadre1981 I just discovered the hibernation setting in windows 10, never going back to the shutdown button :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When battery runs low, in most cases windows will put the laptop to sleep. It still consumes energy, but does so at a lower pace. The laptop could go hours before a procent of battery is dropped, but it will drop.

When a critical level is reached, usually 4%, the system is resumed from sleep and placed in hibernation. This process is seamless.

The difference between sleep and hibernation is the following:

- At sleep, power runs through the mainboard to keep the content that is inside the RAM chips there. Although the power consumption is really low, it does consume power. Waking up a pc from sleep is very fast.
- At hibernation, the content of memory is entirely saved to disk. The more memory you have, the larger the hiberfil.sys file will be, and thus the more time it takes to save this content to disk and resume it from disk. Once the memory has been written to disk, a flag is set so the bootloader knows it has to resume from the hiberfil.sys file rather than doing a normal startup. After that, the system is completely powered down and no memory is being drained anymore. Unless something happens to the harddisk, a system could be kept like this for years and resume like nothing happened. (okay not entirely true, the clock could be out of sync and that could give different complications).

That said, Windows 10 (and also windows 8) comes with a feature called Fast Startup. This essentially does the following when you shutdown windows:

- Close all programs
- Save the remaining content of ram (that at this point should be reduced significantly because no active programs are running, only device drivers)
- Set a flag that the system is in a fast startup state (this is basically the hibernation state, but the startup sequence looks slightly different.

Since Windows 10 v1709, Windows will also save to registry which programs were closed, and reopens them at startup.

So if you want to get the same result as the battery low mechanism, all you need to do is start->shutdown->Sleep.

Comment: I believe the system is not resumed, but rather Windows does a hybrid sleep where it both saves ram to the hard disk so it can resume from hibernation if power is entirely lost, and enters suspend-to-ram so it can resume quickly as long as some power holds in the battery.

Comment: @psusi nope, it will really power down completely. I've tested this by hooking up an energy meter to the system, then performing a normal shutdown. After the system was shutdown, there was 0 watt power usage.

Comment: Yes; when you tell it to shut down.  I was talking about when the battery gets low or you close the lid.

Comment: @psusi ah, that's possible. Power Management settings suggest windows is taking actions though.